# How do I remove the redundant database name from this script?

Tags: mysql

Its been a while since I've done mysql.  What I want to do is to get rid of all the "prs_db" redundancy from the following database creation script.  How do I do this?

```
CREATE DATABASE `prs_db`;

GRANT
  SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE
ON
  `prs_db`.*
TO
  'prs'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'freakingSecret';

GRANT
  ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, DELETE,
  DROP, EXECUTE, INDEX, INSERT, LOCK TABLES, SELECT, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER, UPDATE
ON
  `prs_db`.*
TO
  'prs_admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'evenMoreSecretShhhh';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`USE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)  after your `CREATE` like

```
CREATE DATABASE `prs_db`;
USE `prs_db`;
```

the `USE` statement causes *MySQL to use the `db_name` database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements*